# Forcing a specific HTTP URL request through web proxy

Tags: web-server, proxy, http, redirect, http-proxy

I need to force one specific HTTP request through a web proxy whereas the rest of the HTTP requests should directly go to the web server.

I can use error code `305 Use Proxy response` to redirect my client, but I'm not sure if that would be supported by my client's underlying HTTP stack.

Do any other options exist to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [PAC file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) to make the browser choose the proxy based on the URL. For example:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (url == 'http://example.com/blah') {
        return 'PROXY cache.example.org:3128;
    }
    return 'DIRECT';
}
```

Comment: Which of course would not **force** anything :-)

Comment: @guntbert You can always deny it on the server to prevent incorrectly configured clients from access it directly.

Comment: You are assuming that they have control over the web server? In that case you are right.